# Eclipse console shows broken letters when running AWT Window

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, awt, cjk

I set my VM arguments as follows to get Korean characters on AWT Window buttons to show correctly.

VM arguments in Launch configuration:
[image: VM arguments in Launch configuration]

This solved characters on the AWT Window, but this time characters on Eclipse console are broken.

Broken letters on Eclipse console:
[image: broken letters on Eclipse console]

I checked out that if I remove the arguments, the console works normally but characters on AWT components go wrong.

I want Korean characters be shown on both correctly. Is there any solution for me?

Comment: my guess, it's the encoding. it would be easier if you edited the images in the question, instead of asking us to go to an external link

Comment: @Stultuske Do you mean the encoding of the source code? I've checked out the file is encoded in UTF-8. And as it's my first post on stack overflow, I don't know how to upload directly on the question.

Comment: not the encoding of the source file. the encoding of how/where you try to print your output

Comment: You have specified `-Dfile.encoding=...` twice (hit the _Show Command Line_ button for details). Does specifying the file encoding in the tab _Common_ in the _Encoding_ section and leaving the field _VM arguments_ blank fix your issue?

Comment: @Stultuske A user with a rep of 1 isn't allowed to post images directly. links to imgur are all they can do.

Comment: @howlger No, it didn't help me. The reason I added the arguments was to broken letters on AWT components and it fixed the problem but now the console outputs broken characters. What I don't understand is changing encoding for window affect the one of the console. I think it's just because Eclipse doesn't completely support non-English charaters.

Comment: Specifying `-Dfile.encoding=...` as _VM argument_ will result in a command line with two `-Dfile.encoding=...` (did you check the command line?). As far as I know, the _Console_ view uses the encoding of the _Common_ tab. Make also sure, the font used in the _Console_ view contains Korean characters (in the preferences _General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts: Basic > Text Font_). Eclipse completely supports non-English characters.

Comment: @howlger Here's my command line and I can see only one `-Dfile.encoding=...`  : C:\Users\XXX\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=MS949
-classpath "C:\Users\XXX\eclipse-workspace\Practice\bin"
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages guiprogramming.AwtEx

Comment: @howlger And I also changed the font setting as you said, but it doesn't work, either.

Comment: The _Console_ view uses the encoding of the _Common_ tab (independent from that, for your application to run `-Dfile.encoding=...` can be overridden via _VM arguments_). Did you get exactly the same for `MS949` and `UTF-8`? What font exactly did you try? Please add the Java code and output from the _Console_ view as text to your question. What happens when you copy the _Console_ output into the Java editor?

Comment: Finally, I fixed this. The encoding of workspace(preferences>General>Workspace) was set as "UTF-8", so I changed it into "MS949" then the console window shows correct character. the difference between workspace and file encoding settings cause this inconsistency. Thanks for help of all of you guys.